# FFmpeg multiple commands (convert, then join)

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

I have e.g. file 1.mp4, 2.mp4, 3.mp4 etc. that needs converting

```
for %i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -y -i "%i" -vf scale=1280:720 -crf 17 -c:v libx265 "%~ni.mp4"
```

Then I concatenate

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i xmylist.txt -crf 17 -c copy x1.mp4
```

Now, I wanna do this in one step and failed with

```
for %i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -y -i "%i" -vf scale=1280:720 -crf 17 -c:v libx265, -f concat -safe 0 -i xmylist.txt -crf 17 -c copy "%~ni.mp4"
```

How to fuse these two together properly?
The error I got was

> Option vf (set video filters) cannot be applied to input url
> xmylist.txt -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output
> file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
> Error parsing options for input file xmylist.txt. Error opening input
> files: Invalid argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

`for %i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -y -i "%i" -vf scale=1280:720 -crf 17 -c:v libx265 "%~ni.mp4" & ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i xmylist.txt -crf 17 -c copy "%~ni.mp4"`

or this in a batch:

`for %%i in (*.mp4) DO (`

`ffmpeg -y -i "%%i" -vf scale=1280:720 -crf 17 -c:v libx265 "%%~ni.mp4"`

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i xmylist.txt -crf 17 -c copy "%%~ni.mp4"`

`)`

although paying attention to what you are trying to do is it good to do it this way being you are concatenating the same file that is already a single file?

being you cannot use more than one set of () in a for loop here is a possible solution using 3 batch files:

You use start command because if you just put it in there it will run both batches and close instantly.

Batch 1:

`start "Batch2.bat"`

`start "Batch3.bat"`

Batch 2:

`for %%i in (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -y -i "%%i" -vf scale=1280:720 -crf 17 -c:v libx265 "%%~ni.mp4"`

Batch 3:

`for %%i in (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i xmylist.txt -crf 17 -c copy "x1.mp4"`

Please let me know:).  I can look into a much more advanced cmd at home later tonight to help you out with this.